# How would you associate QoS with WCF?

Tags: wcf, service, soa, qos

In SOA(Service Oriented Architecture), service composition usually consider the QoS or the Quality of Service during the composition stage. If I am going to create a WCF-based SOA, how would I get the QoS in WCF context?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about making service claims and exposing them for consumption vis-a-vis WS-QoS, there is no first-party support for this.  You are looking at creating your own Service Behavior to implement this (doable, but difficult).

For monitoring and business logic based on QoS metrics, you have a much bigger job ahead of you.  There are several metrics WCF publishes to Perf Mon, but it's probably not enough depending on your needs.

Seeing as how you have some fairly enterprisey needs, have you considered a combination of Biztalk and the WCF LOB adapters?  Here's a link to take a look:

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/technologies/wcflobadaptersdk.mspx